# Is there a narration about the following story related to the Day of Judgement?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity, day-of-judgement

<sup>It goes along the lines of what is mentioned in a lecture and on the internet, which is **not** the Hadith mentioned in Sahih Muslim ([190a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:190a)), but is still somehow similar to this following narration (if it is true):</sup>

<sup>***The story***: The Prophet (ﷺ) laughed one day and so his Sahabah asked: "*What are you smiling about?*" He said: "*I was looking into the Day of Judgment*" - and every time the Prophet (ﷺ) saw the Day of Judgement, he would (usually) cry or panic and worry for everyone. But this time, he smiled and he said: "*I smiled because the People, on the Day of Judgment, a group of them will laugh*", they asked: "*Who are 'they'*" and he said: "*They are People on the Judgement Day who will laugh*", and the Sahabah asked: "*Who are they?*" The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*They are people who committed sins and they will laugh on the Day of Judgement [...] and the people will ask them what they were laughing about.* They will say: "*We've sinned [...] and we repented [...] and our sins became good deeds!*"</sup>

---

<sup><sup>This is the only [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rn7eTIVJPwU) that I could find which is refering to this narration, but it is not revealing a reference or its authenticity.</sup></sup>

Comment: i am very skeptical about this narration. haven't found anything with the exact wording in multiple hadith databases.(9 to be exact) the search continues, insha Allah.

Answer (score -1):

One well-known narration related to the Day of Judgement is the Hadith of Gabriel, in which the Angel Gabriel appears to Prophet Muhammad and asks him about the Islamic faith, the signs of the Day of Judgement, and the qualities of faith and righteousness. This Hadith emphasizes the importance of faith and good deeds in preparing for the Day of Judgement and attaining salvation in the hereafter.

Other narrations related to the Day of Judgement describe the various stages of the afterlife, including the questioning in the grave, the crossing of the Bridge of Sirat, and the presentation of deeds before Allah. These narrations emphasize the importance of living a righteous life and striving to please Allah in order to attain success in the hereafter.

Overall, there are many narrations and stories related to the Day of Judgement in Islamic teachings, which emphasize the importance of faith, good deeds, and preparing for the afterlife. These teachings encourage Muslims to live a virtuous life and seek Allah's forgiveness and mercy in order to attain success in the hereafter.
To find out how Allah will judge us on the Judgment Day please follow the link: https://www.islamiqate.com/4269/how-will-allah-judge-us-on-the-day-of-judgement

Answer (score -2):

I hope you are doing well. I believe this might be the hadith you are referring to:

https://sunnah.com/shamail:228

Comment: That is the same hadith from Muslim (190a) that I mentioned in my question, which is similar, but not the one which we are searching.

Comment: Hello, the only place I see that is that it is mentioned in a youtube video. It would be more helpful to ask the youtube video creator to see where that source was from. The other thing I could think of is that they used their own words to describe the hadith.